# WP Docker container fails Connection Error: (2002)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I'm launching the following `docker-compose`:

```
version: '2'
services:
 wp_db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: imaxinaria_mysql2
  volumes:
    - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    MYSQL_USER: wordpress
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
 wp_web:
  image: nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  #log_driver: syslog
  links:
    - wordpress
  volumes:
    - ./wp:/var/www/html
    - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem
 wordpress:
  depends_on:
    - wp_db
  image: wordpress:latest
  container_name: imaxinaria2
  volumes:
    - "./wp:/var/www/html"
    - "./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini"
  links:
    - wp_db:mysql    
  expose:
    - 80
    - 443
  restart: always
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

And getting the following ERROR on WP continer log:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10
Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;


 events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;

default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";  
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    lab.imaxinaria.org;
  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lab.imaxinaria.org/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lab.imaxinaria.org/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem; 

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;


  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lab.imaxinaria.org/chain.pem; 

  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
      root           /var/www/html;
      fastcgi_pass   wp_db:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }    
}
}
```

Could you help me to solve this? Anyway my goal is to launch several wp with persistence behind a Nginx proxy with SSL. If there is a better way let me know.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I tried to use this image as well https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress but getting same results.
Also checked wp-config.php and everything seems alright with  DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD and DB_HOST. 
Also found that this error could be a bad linking between mysql and wp containers, but they are supposed to be linked as the rule is given on `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved erasing `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306` from `docker-compose.yml`